# iPhone app to show me my locations database

Tags: iphone, ipad, applications, gps

It seems that Apple stores GPS information (or GPS information of  hot spots) in the iPhone/iPad, and a hacker invented [a tool](http://petewarden.github.com/iPhoneTracker/) to show the info on Mac. I think this is a pretty useful feature for automatically recording what I've been visiting.

Are there any apps for iPad/iPhone to track my GPS info so that I can extract the data to display on Mac later?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid that, without a jailbreak, you won't find any apps that do this for you using your 'locations database' (the "tracking" you're talking about). There are two main reasons:

1: [According to Apple](http://www.apple.com/pr/library/2011/04/27location_qa.html), the file is protected. Besides, apps don't get access to system files anyway.

2: Such an app would probably scare some people, and Apple would never allow it on the App store.

Maybe we'll see some apps for jailbroken phones, but I wouldn't expect anything to come to the standard App Store.

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of Apps that can store GPS co-ordinates for you.  Have a look through the Navigation section on the app store.  [Paths](http://itunes.apple.com/au/app/paths/id337479613?mt=8) is a popular choice.  You can then export the data that is collected and use it in a variety of ways on your Mac (including Google Earth etc).

Note: This **does not** use the GPS data that Apple have been storing.  This data will not be available after the next iOS update as written about [here](http://www.apple.com/pr/library/2011/04/27location_qa.html).

Comment: Apple won't be making the data unavailable after the update, they're just going to stop including it in iTunes Device Backups. I.e., the phone still has and uses it.

Comment: If the location data is not in the iTunes Device Backups and using a non-jailbroken phone, then it's unavailable right?

Comment: Right. But it's equally unavailable now. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

While not *exactly* what you're *requesting*, [Google Latitude](http://www.google.com/latitude) has [an app](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/google-latitude/id306586497?mt=8) that does exactly what you want on iOS 4+. For iOS 3, you can use [Longitude](http://modmyi.com/forums/iphone-news/693826-longitude-keeps-you-connected-google-latitude-realtime-gps-tracking.html) along with it as well, on cydia.

Latitude basically keeps track of every place you've been. The app polls data in it ever so often and you can also "check in" from any web browser just by logging in.

It even has a funny chart of how much you've traveled compared with the distance to the moon:

[image: my personal Latitude's funny chart]

Comment: That's some kind of cool.

Comment: @hobs it is, isn't it? :P  also, under "view and manage" you can export everything to `KML` (and Google Earth) as well.